# How can I get a cartoon filter effect over the camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am starting an app and the first thing I need to do is make the image from the camera have a comic book style effect. I know how to do overlays, but I can't think of how I could achieve this using only overlays. Does anyone have any experience doing this, or know how I could go about it?

Comment: me too need this.. have you got any solution for this..?